# The change in DataTable is not visible during filtering

Tags: c#, datatable, windows-forms-designer

In the DataTable table I have some data that the program modifies on the fly. After this modification, it tries to filter the table but no changes can be seen in it - i.e. filter (DataView) does not see these changed cells. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like to me that you did not call the AcceptChanges after you do modification to your DataTable.

Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Data_DataTable_AcceptChanges).